# How do I use Tcl to puts string containing curly bracket { and }?

Tags: escaping, tcl

I am writing code to generate Tcl script, it generates script that includes "puts {blah}".

But the script will fail if I try to puts `{` or `}`. I thought the escape is '\' but it didn't work:

```
% puts {}}
extra characters after close-brace
% puts {\}}
\}
% puts {\{}
\{
```

`puts{{}` also does not work but `puts{{}}` works.

Similarly, if `\` is the last character of the string, the command will not complete.

I have checked the 12 rules of Tcl (http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm) but I don't see a solution to my problem.

Comment: Isn't your string in a variable since your input is a stream? `puts`-ing a variable containing braces shouldn't cause any issues. So your problem is probably not well defined or is elsewhere. Would be helpful if you could have a reproducible example of the issue as close as the problem you have.

Comment: I am generating a tcl script. Therefore, the output will be something like `puts {this is a test}` where `this is a test` is part of the input file.

Answer (score 2):

Braces can quote *most* things, but *cannot* quote unbalanced braces. That's when you have to stop using braces for quoting and do it all with backslashes (which can quote anything, but which are annoying and ugly). Indeed, that's what Tcl's own list-quoting engine does.

```
# Double quotes can quote things in some cases.
set a "This is{ an example"
set b "and so }is this"
puts [list $a $b]
```

```
This\ is\{\ an\ example and\ so\ \}is\ this
```

If you're generating commands, you're *strongly* advised to use `list` to do it, or the equivalent code at the C level, which is hooked in behind `Tcl_NewListObj()` and friends. It gets this sort of thing right so you don't have to. (It also has some performance optimisations when it comes to execution as a bonus.)

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the answer I'm looking for. But I still don't understand why braces cannot take a '\' in the end? What is the point of a escape if it is printed and does not work properly?

Answer (score 0):

As per rule, braces should be balanced and anything placed in between braces will be treated literally. These are the ones causing this behaviour for you.

```
% puts "{"
{
% puts "}"
}
% puts "{{}"
{{}
%
```

Use double quotes for enclosing the string.

Comment: It happens that I am processing input as a stream and I do not know ahead of time if my string contains braces or not. If I use double quotes, I would have to escape the double quotes, which I know is quite common for my input, and potentially other characters

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to read an input stream that might contain unbalanced braces and use the text on that stream for scripted output you are going to have to either a) count braces and balance them somehow, or b) use double quotes. If the input stream contains double quote characters it's quite easy to `string map` them to escaped double quotes.

You might also get some mileage out of the `list` command, which is quite clever with escaping. If your input is `foo }bar [baz]`, stored in the variable `foo`, you can use the command `puts [list puts $foo]` to output the script

```
puts foo\ \}bar\ \[baz\]
```

which reproduces the input.

Another solution, if noone needs to read the generated scripts, is to convert every character into a character code, so that `foo} bar` becomes e.g. `\x66\x6f\x6f\x7d\x20\x62\x61\x72` (which can be output directly). One can of course exclude alphanumerics from this conversion to preserve some readability. The main point of this exercise is that you don't need any quoting at all.

There are probably more elegant methods as well, but without knowing your data it's hard to make good suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
% puts \{\}\}
{}}
% puts \{\{\}
{{}
% puts this\ is\ it\ {\}\}
this is it {}}
```

This may help you 
I just used the concept of the @Peter Lewerin